# /Applications/eclipse_4.4.2/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

[image]

I solved this problem a long time. Who encountered this problem.thanks!

Comment: please add your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

Check what `compileSdkVersion` version you have already in your `build.gradle`file. Chenge to `23`, if you have another one.

Try also `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart` as well `Build -> Clean` and `Build -> Rebuild project` to solve doubled dependencies.

Hope it help

Comment: add your build.gradle

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

Comment: edit your post above and add it, it doesn't seems to full content

Answer (score 0):

Here's my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    repositories {`enter code here`
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: change `'23.0.1'` to `23.0.2` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'` to com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1' - then `Rebuild` project